# Error querying database. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException: QProfile is missing

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to restart SonarQube and ran into an issue with the QProfile is missing but I'm not sure what to do to address this.

```
2015.07.06 12:50:31 ERROR [o.s.s.p.PlatformServletContextListener]  Fail to start server
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException: QProfile is missing
### The error may exist in org.sonar.core.qualityprofile.db.ActiveRuleMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.core.qualityprofile.db.ActiveRuleMapper.selectAllKeysAfterTimestamp-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT     r.plugin_rule_key as "rulefield",     r.plugin_name as "repository",     qp.kee as "profileKey"     FROM active_rules a           LEFT JOIN rules_profiles qp ON qp.id=a.profile_id     LEFT JOIN rules r ON r.id = a.rule_id          WHERE a.updated_at IS NULL or a.updated_at >= ?
### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException: QProfile is missing
```

Comment: Looks similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540148/sonarqube-qprofile-is-missing

Comment: I already tried removing the es folder and it still wouldn't start.  I still get the same error

Comment: If you want help, please add more information to your question: which version of SonarQube, longer log to better undertand when this problem happens.